# Widen the slider in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, slider, qtableview

Is there an easy way to widen the slider in the `QTableView` object?

[image]

Is it possible without subclassing the `QTableView`? If there is no other way, which method should be modified?
I would appreciate all help.

Comment: There is (get the vertical scrollbar, change its sizing...), but *why*? It will make your application look not native, which goes against all good practices.

Comment: I need to optimmize the application for touchscreen its hard to hit the default slider with your finger because its cery small.

Comment: But again, you''re not supposed to scroll using the slider on a touchscreen; Apple taught this lesson to the world 10 years ago. You're supposed to do a pan gesture (2 finger movement), which should work out of the box.

Comment: And if I am using a non multitouch resistive screen?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it is possible to do literally what you're asking, but the end results will result in a horrible UI that doesn't match today's standards of UX. If you really want to go down that way, again, check `verticalScrollBar()` and resize it or similar.

Comment: Then you're not supposed to use a look&feel developed for precision input (a mouse). At least I'd immediately turn on all the accessibility options in Windows to make all the controls 2/4 times their size.

Comment: It seems like I would have to do make a new stylesheet or something like that. Didnt want to go that deep only for making the scrollbar wider. The `QScrolbar` itself doesnt implement any methods like "set width' or anything.

Answer (score 1):

use [QScrollBar Styling](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar) in your `QTableView::StyleSheet`